# Script timed out before returning headers with php set_time_limit(0) runs fine by SSH

Tags: php, apache, timeout

I have a script which generates a report for a customer as a CSV, writes it to a file then uses`readfile()` to output to the browser.

I'm having an issue where a large report (takes about 11 minutes to generate, is about 700kb in size) is throwing a 500 error. Apache says "Script timed out before returning headers"

I have tried using `set_time_limit(0)` in the script and setting the max_execution_time in php.ini to 900 (15 minutes) to no avail. I have `error_log()` calls emailing throughout the script and they report that the script was generated OK, and `ini_get('max_execution_time')` inside the script returns 0 (I'm assuming this means unlimited).
If I log in via SSH and run the script using php scriptname.php it runs fine and outputs the CSV to the shell.

Could there be another setting, perhaps inside apache, that is causing the timeout issue? I know i should move this script to a cron perhaps but right now time is an issue (isn't it always with clients) so I'd like to just resolve the timeout issue.

Comment: no customer will sit and wait for 11 minutes, run it in the background and notify them when its done (cli script default time limit is 0(unlimited) )

Comment: Do you need the file as it would be better to just dump the output to the browser one line at a time after setting the correct headers.  That I have found is way more efficient and as a bonus it streams the download without them waiting for the file to write and then be read.  Also, have a look at fopen('php://output') to use fputcsv.

Comment: You can try to increase Timeout directive in apache configuration. http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#timeout